# jQuery rearrange DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, jquery-animate

I'm a little confused why this is not working how it's supposed to.

I have a list of `<div>`s that wrap around based on the size of the page. But clicking the div it `.animate()` the width of the clicked div and animates the divs after it closer together and stacks them.

This all works except the last stacked div, despite having plenty of room still gets knocked down to the next row.

please see my code on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZHYRq/2/

```
$.each($('.employee-box'), function(i, el) {
$(el).addClass("top-" + (Math.round($(el).offset().top)));
return $(el).css('position', 'relative').attr('data-left', Math.round($(el).offset().left));
});

$('.employee-image').hover(function(e) {
    var $employee;
    $employee = $(e.target).parents('.employee-box');
    if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
        return $($employee.find('a.bio')).addClass('highlight');
    } else {
        return $($employee.find('a.bio')).removeClass('highlight');
    }
});

$('.employee-image, a.bio').click(function(e) {
    var $employee, is_expanded, speed;
    speed = 150;
    $employee = $(e.target).parents('.employee-box');
    is_expanded = $employee.hasClass('bio-expanded');
    if ($('.bio-expanded').length > 0) {
        $.when(collapse_previous_bio(speed)).then(function() {
            if (!is_expanded) {
                return expand_bio_box($employee, speed);
            }
        });
    } else {
        expand_bio_box($employee, speed);
    }
    return false;
});


var collapse_previous_bio = function(speed) {
    var klass;
    klass = "." + $('.bio-expanded').attr('class').match(/top-\d{1,5}/)[0];
    $('.bio-expanded .bio-block').fadeOut(speed, function() {
      $('.bio-expanded').animate({
        width: "185px"
      }, speed);
      $(klass).animate({
        left: '0px'
      }, speed);
      $('.bio-expanded').removeClass('bio-expanded');
    });
  };

  var expand_bio_box = function($employee, speed) {
    var curr_left, klass;
    klass = "." + $employee.attr('class').match(/top-\d{1,5}/)[0];
    curr_left = parseInt($employee.data('left'));

// comment out the $.when block and un-comment out the collapse_others() to see the other elements collapse as they should
$.when(collapse_others(klass, curr_left)).then(function() {
  $employee.animate({
    width: "392px"
  }, speed, function() {
    $employee.find('.bio-block').fadeIn(speed);
    $employee.addClass('bio-expanded');
  });
});
// collapse_others(klass, curr_left)


};



var collapse_others = function(klass, curr_left) {
    var left_pos;
    left_pos = 0;
    $.each($(klass), function(i, el) {
      var el_left;
      el_left = parseInt($(el).data('left'));
      $(el).css({
        zIndex: 100 - i
      });
      if (el_left > curr_left) {
        $(el).animate({
          left: "-" + left_pos + "px"
        }, 100);
        left_pos += 100;
      }
    });
  };
```

I'm not sure what is wrong here. Any thoughts?

Comment: It doesnt seem to happen to me in Chrome .

Comment: one thing more: try to click first div, and then second div -> last div is moved down (or try to click fourth or fifth div, last div is knocked down again)- simple, content width is > than container width... you have to find a way to 'close'/resize previous divs in row (e.g. close -> div 1, 2, 3 if fourth div is clicked)...

Comment: It's moving the last box down to the next line despite the new available room b/c of the stacking. And I am closing other boxes before expanding the next. Something to do with the JS ignoring the elements stacking thus not being as wide...